# I can't find a 'objectForKey' in 'NSMutableArray' in Xcode6.1.1

Tags: xcode, swift, nsmutablearray

I keep getting an error saying,

'`NSMutableArray`' does not have a member named '`objectForKey`'

Please help me I'm just a beginner at **Xcode Swift** and programming...

Comment: You need to learn some general programming concepts before jumping deep into a new language. **Arrays don't store key-value pairs.** An array is indexed using integers. You won't find an `objectForKey:` method on an array. (But you could tell this **if** only you bothered to read the documentation. There's an `objectAtIndex:` method instead.) – By the way, the language is called Swift, not "Xcode Swift". Xcode is an IDE. It doesn't matter whether you are a beginner in using Xcode – you don't have a problem with your IDE, you have a problem with the language.

Answer (score 0):

`objectForKey` is an NSDictionary method because an array has no keys.

Try `objectAtIndex` or `myArray[index]`

See: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/